# How do I access AngularJS' global `angular` variable in Angular and TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm working on a big monolithic AngularJS application and want to add an Angular (as in Angular 4) component. Unfortunately, the AngularJS project's build system is largely fixed and the only thing I can do is adjust the project's `index.html` and, for instance, add additional `<script>` tags to load my Angular code. My question now is how I access AngularJS' global `angular` variable in my Angular project's TypeScript files to downgrade my Angular component and make it accessible to AngularJS, *without* adding the whole AngularJS library as a dependency to my Angular project since it's already bundled in the AngularJS project's JS files that the `index.html` loads.

To explain the situation a bit more in detail: I've followed the [upgrade guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) to bootstrap the AngularJS app from Angular, like so:

```
// src/app/app.module.ts of the Angular project
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private upgrade: UpgradeModule) { }
  ngDoBootstrap() {
    // Bootstrap AngularJS app
    this.upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, ['my-angularjs-app']);
  }
}
```

The files `src/main.ts` and `src/app/app.component.ts` are unchanged compared to a default `$ ng new my-app` project. Now, I run `$ ng build --prod` to produce production-ready JavaScript files that I can include in the AngularJS project's `index.html` as mentioned above. (Specifically, the Angular files are loader *after* the AngularJS files.)

Now I would like to make `AppComponent` available to AngularJS. [This section of the guide](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#using-angular-components-from-angularjs-code) suggests that I add the following lines to the above `app.module.ts`:

```
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

angular.module('my-angularjs-app')
  .directive(
    'my-ng2-component',
    downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

However, the `angular` variable obviously is not available and the TypeScript compiler complains about that. How do I change that? I've tried the following things to no avail:

1. Add a line `declare var angular: any` or a line `let angular = window.angular`. This results in `Cannot find namespace 'angular'` when adding the downgrade code from above.
2. Add `@types/angular` as a dependency to my Angular project and add a line `import * as angular from 'angular'`. (This results in `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angular'` when adding the downgrade code.)
3. Like 2) but add a line `/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/angular/index.d.ts" />` to the top of the file
4. Like 2) but add a line `/// <reference types="angular" />` to the top of the file.

3) and 4) result in the following error message:

> 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module.
>   Consider adding an import instead.

The latter seems to be related to the following two issues on GitHub:

- [Built-in support for UMD module definitions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7125)
- [Consider allowing access to UMD globals from modules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10178)

Is there any way that actually works? The upgrade guide, unfortunately, is very vague when it comes to this.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found a variant that seems to work. I added the following lines to `app.module.ts`:

```
import { downgradeComponent } from '@angular/upgrade/static';

declare var angular: any; // <-- Added declaration

angular.module('my-angularjs-app')
  .directive(
    'my-ng2-component',
    downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }) // <-- Note that there's no type conversion here anymore.
  );
```